# Evaluate this limit of integration in Complex analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am trying assignments of Complex analysis and I couldn't evaluate this particular integral.

> Find the limit $\int_{|z|=R} |\sin(z)/z | |dz| $ as $R\to\infty$.

I am unable to see which result I should use and also there is confusion due to dz being in modulus and also $\sin(z) /z$.

Can you please tell significance of modulus here and how to compute the limit.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that
$$
 \int_{|z|=R} \frac{|\sin(z)|}{|z|} |dz| = \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{|\sin(R e^{it})|}{|R e^{it}|} R \, dt = \int_0^{2 \pi} |\sin(R e^{it})| \, dt \, .
$$

Generally, for $z= x+iy$,
$$
 |\sin(z)|^2 = \sin^2(x) + \sinh^2(y) \implies |\sin(z)| \ge |\sinh(y)| \, .
$$
If we restrict the integration to the arc $z = R e^{it}$ with $\pi/4 \le t \le 3\pi /4$ then
$$
|\sin(R e^{it})| \ge \sinh(R \sin(t)) \ge \sinh(\frac{R}{\sqrt 2}) \, .
$$
(This is what @reuns meant with the comment that *“$|\sin(z)|$ is large near $iR$”*).

It follows that
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} |\sin(R e^{it})| \, dt \ge
\int_{\pi/4}^{3 \pi/4} |\sin(R e^{it})| \, dt \\
\ge \int_{\pi/4}^{3 \pi/4} \sinh(\frac{R}{\sqrt 2}) \, dt = \frac \pi 2 \sinh(\frac{R}{\sqrt 2}) \, ,
$$
and that grows to infinity for $R \to \infty$.

Comment: Can you please tell how you deduced that $|sin (Re^{it})| \geq sinh(R sint) $ and how does $sinh(R sin(t)) \geq sinh (R /\sqrt2)$?

Comment: @Avenger: The first inequality follows from $|\sin(z)| \ge |\sinh(y)|$, applied to $z=Re^{it} = R\cos(t) + iR \sin(t)$. The second inequality follows from $\sin(t) \ge 1/\sqrt 2$ for $\pi/2 \le t \le 3\pi /2$.

Comment: but $sin (\pi)$ =0 so i don't think that 2nd inequality is true.

Comment: @Avenger: You are completely right, that was a stupid error! It should be $\pi/4 \le t \le 3\pi /4$, I have fixed it in the answer. – The idea is that the imaginary part of $e^{it}$ is bounded below on some arc of the unit circle.

Answer (score -1):

Hint : it is $\infty$.

$              $

Comment: Please add some explanation  to the answer. I am unable to see how to prove it $\infty$?

Comment: $|\sin(z)|$ is large near $iR$